# Using vim-latex with latexmk and evince results in garbled text (GLib-GObject-CRITICAL)

Tags: vim, latex, evince

When I compile a latex file in vim with the vim-latex plugin with `\ll` using`latexmk`, my vim terminal text content gets littered with error messages like the following dispersed through the text:

```
(evince:10013): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

It looks to me as if evince dumps its log output into the vim window, can I prevent that somehow?

**Solved**
Thanks to @maxschlepzig, I solved it by adding `let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = "evince 2>/dev/null"`to my `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those messages come from evince. They are emitted when evince detected a PDF file change and it reloads the file.

You can workaround this via redirecting `stderr` of evince to `/dev/null`. That means you can search for the evince call in the vim-latex plugin source and replace something like

```
evince <OPTS> <INPUT>
```

with:

```
evince <OPTS> <INPUT> 2>/dev/null
```

Alternatively, you can place a small wrapper script in your `PATH` - when running vim with the vim-latex plugin. For example something like this:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/local/bin
$ cat ~/local/bin/evince
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/evince "$@" 2>/dev/null
$ chmod 755 ~/local/bin/evince
$ PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH vim some_latex_file
```

Answer (score 1):

In some occasions. `evince` prints error messages to `/dev/stdout`. I add

```
>> /dev/null
```

to the evince command line. I have

```
$pdf_previewer = 'evince %S >/dev/null 2>/dev/null';
```

in my `~/.latexmkrc` file to get a clean output from `latexmk`